# Django ChoiceField, ModelChoiceField validation

Tags: django, validation

I see that [`forms.ChoiceField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L747) is using [this code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L788) to validate the value:

```
def validate(self, value):
    """
    Validates that the input is in self.choices.
    """
    super(ChoiceField, self).validate(value)
    if value and not self.valid_value(value):
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid_choice'],
            code='invalid_choice',
            params={'value': value},
        )

def valid_value(self, value):
    "Check to see if the provided value is a valid choice"
    text_value = force_text(value)
    for k, v in self.choices:
        if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)):
            # This is an optgroup, so look inside the group for options
            for k2, v2 in v:
                if value == k2 or text_value == force_text(k2):
                    return True
        else:
            if value == k or text_value == force_text(k):
                return True
    return False
```

and [`forms.models.ModelChoiceField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L1117) [this code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L1215):

```
def validate(self, value):
    return Field.validate(self, value)
```

Q1. Why Django uses validation to check if the selected value (from dropdown) is indeed in the choice list for [`forms.ChoiceField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L747)?

Q2. When Django uses the validation from Q1, to check if the value is indeed in the choice list, why does not also check if the selected value is in the model records for [`forms.models.ModelChoiceField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L1117)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The validation process starts from [form.full_clean()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/forms.py#L370) where you have [form._clean_fields()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/forms.py#L388) and [form._clean_form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/forms.py#L410) executed in this order.

Now if you take a closer look at what `form._clean_fields()` do, you will probably notice that it only calls `field.clean(value, initial)` and collects the results into a `cleaned_data` dict. So the interesting part is at [field.clean](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/fields.py#L153), lets see what happens there:

```
def clean(self, value):
    """
    Validate the given value and return its "cleaned" value as an
    appropriate Python object. Raise ValidationError for any errors.
    """
    value = self.to_python(value)
    self.validate(value)
    self.run_validators(value)
    return value
```

First, we have a `to_python` call, followed by `validate` and finishing with `run_validators`.

So in terms of `ModelChoiceField` when you reach the `.validate` method, your choice is already a Model instance, thats why, this kind of validation (from Q2) is happening inside the [to_python](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/models.py#L1216) method.

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value in self.empty_values:
        return None
    try:
        key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
        value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})
    except (ValueError, TypeError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
    return value
```

Answer (score 2):

one thing i can say is for forms.ChoiceField the input are coming from the user perspective means a user can use inspect element and enter a choice which doesnt appear from the backend .

but for models one the choices are directly coming from the backend or the database

Comment: He can do the same for a model choice field. In that case the form will not validate the value. The model will. I still leave the bounty for my question open..